# Why is Segmentation Core Dumped during execution of this c snippet

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, segmentation-fault, malloc

The following is a C Code which implements a **graph** :.The code throws a segmentation fault after execution. I tried debugging the program using **gdb** and setting the **break point
before the first malloc operation** .The value of the buffer before the malloc operation is 0x00.....How can i overcome this problem and why is this happening?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
typedef struct graph
{
int v;
int e;
int **adj;
}graph;

int main()
{

int i,u,v;
    graph *g=(graph*)malloc(sizeof(graph)); // first malloc call
    scanf(" %d %d",&(g->v),&(g->v));

    g->adj=malloc(sizeof((g->v)*(g->v)));


    for(u=0;u<(g->v);u++)
        {
            for(v=0;v<(g->v);v++)
            g->adj[u][v]=0;
        }
    printf(" Enter input");

        for(i=0;i<(g->e);i++){
            scanf("%d %d",&u,&v);
            g->adj[u][v]=1;
            g->adj[v][u]=1;

            }
printf("print matriix ");

    for(u = 0; u<(g->v); u++) {

        for(v = 0; v<(g->v) ; u++)
        printf("%d",(g->adj[u][v]));
        printf("\n");
    }


return 0;
}
```

Comment: why don't you use calloc instead? then you do not need to initialize to 0

Comment: @ChristianTernus OK, that's better.

Comment: @Kevin Overzealous code formatter extension. Got to stop using it.

Comment: you should use fgets() and sscanf() instead to avoid issues with the input buffer, makes your life easier.

Comment: `g->adj` is an array of (uninitialised) pointers; not a 2-dim array. Also the size needs to be multiplied by `sizeof *g->adj`.

Answer (score 0):

> `scanf(" %d %d",&(g->v),&(g->v));`
>   `g->adj=malloc(sizeof((g->v)*(g->v)));`

These lines don't look right. Perhaps one of the expressions was supposed to be `g->e`?

In any case, for the code as written, it is unpredictable whether `g->v` will be the first or the second scanned number. And `g->e` is left uninitialized, but you use it in a later loop.

Also, as BSH noted in a deleted answer, `sizeof((g->v)*(g->v))` is going to evaluate to 4 on most current machines. You want: `malloc(g->v * g->e * sizeof(int))`. And you want `adj` to be `int*`, not `int**`.

Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or [address sanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/) to find a fix bugs like this.